# Android SharedPreferences empty after re-opening app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Sorry if this has already been asked, I've looked for hours at similar questions, but nothing seems to work.

I am saving `SharedPreferences` on login like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_CREDENTIALS_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(PREFS_LOGIN_EMAIL_KEY, email);
editor.putString(PREFS_LOGIN_TOKEN_KEY, token);
editor.apply(); // have also tried .commit()
```

Now when I reopen the app, I check that those strings exist in the `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_CREDENTIALS_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String token =  sharedPrefs.getString(PREFS_LOGIN_TOKEN_KEY, null);
String email =  sharedPrefs.getString(PREFS_LOGIN_EMAIL_KEY, null);
```

In the emulator, I get back the same token and email every time. Even when I re-install the app. But on a real device, every time I re-open the app, `token` and `email` are `null`.

and If I do this:

```
sharedPrefs.getAll()
```

I get `{}` (empty dictionary, hash map, whatever you want to call it)

Could there be a setting or a permission that makes the device not persist the prefs?

Comment: Where in your activity are you editing your `SharedPreferences?`

Comment: Its on a button tap, inside a callback to an API server. (Using RetroFit)